# $Metadata url returns 404 with Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.0-rc2

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, .net-5

After updating to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` from `7.5.8` to `8.0.0-rc2` the `~/odata/$metadata` url is not working anymore, it just returns `404 - Not found.`

Before I file a bug, am I doing the configuration wrong?

I followed [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-odata-8-0-preview-for-net-5/) and the somewhat updated documentation in the [Git repo](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData).

Here is my original `Startup.cs` for `7.5.8`:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRouting();
        services.AddOData();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });
    }
}
```

And here my changed `Startup.cs` for `8.0.0-rc2`:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.AddModel("odata", GetEdmModel()));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

(I removed the irrelevant parts that haven't changed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I had to change the sdk in the csproj file from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`.

(Basically the project is a .NET 5 [SDK-style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview) Windows Service / BackgroundWorker with an Asp.Net Core API included.)

It seems this was not an issue with earlier versions before 8.*

Comment: Do you mean your project is a ASP.NET Classic project?

Comment: @SamXu a .NET 5 Asp.Net Core [SDK-style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview) project

Comment: I have Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web in the csproj.  Same problem.